# Paperclip upload file from mobile

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, image-uploading

I need to send and image to a rails api from my ios mobile application and store it with paperclip. This is my json request.

```
{
 attachment:{
   tempfile: #conversion in base 64,
   original_file_name: "file.jpg",
   content_type: "image/jpg"
 }
}
```

Is there any params i am missing? It seems that paperclip isn't able to rebuild the file from the hash. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I relize that all the info i need are in the base64 encode